# I am setting up RAFT Ordering service in Hyperledger Fabric network. I am confused about server certificate and server key

Tags: ssl, hyperledger, raft

I am getting failed to know that what is meant by the server.key and server.crt. I am using my own fabric-ca-server to generate tls certificates. I am successful with solo on tls but getting failed to setup raft service. The only confusing thing is what is this server certificate and server key. I am using ca-cert.pem from tls root server. is server certificate and server key is the private key and signcert from the root tls server?

General.TLS.Enabled = true
General.TLS.PrivateKey = fully qualified path of the file that contains the server private key
General.TLS.Certificate = fully qualified path of the file that contains the server certificate
General.TLS.RootCAs = fully qualified path of the file that contains the certificate chain of the CA that issued TLS server certificate

Thanking you in anticipation

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give my explanation，you can find three files which are related with tls:**ca.crt**,**server.crt**,**server.key**.**ca.crt** is the root ca crt of server.crt,**server.crt** is the cert of orderer,**server.key** is the privete key of orderer.

1. orderer1 sends a hello to show her intent to communicate with orderer2 with TLS.
2. orderer2 presents a certificate(server.crt) which includes orderer2's identity and orderer2's public key, which is issued by a CA(tlsca.example.com) with CA’s signature.
3. orderer1 trusts this CA(tlsca.example.com), and verifies CA’s signature(use ca's plublic key which obtain from ca.crt) in orderer2's certificate. Upon successful, orderer1 knows she is talking to orderer2, and inside the certificate(server.crt) orderer1 obtains orderer2's public key.
4. orderer1 encrypts some secret using this public key.
5. orderer2 obtains that secret by decrypting the received message with his own private key(server.key)
6. Based on some mathematics, orderer1 and orderer2 come up with some shared material, which can only be known by orderer1 and orderer2, and cannot be deduced without orderer1's and orderer2's private key.
7. With the same shared secret, now orderer1 and orderer2 can communicate safely their messages.

you can reference https://kctheservant.medium.com/tls-in-hyperledger-fabric-b38fccb8614c to obtain more information